# How to Change the Background Color of a Slide in Google Apps Script with Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, background, google-slides

#### I have been trying to figure out how to change the background color of a slide in Google Apps Script.

I tried `setConcreteColor(DARK1, "#FF00FF");`, and it gave me the error code:

`ReferenceError: DARK1 is not defined`.

Can someone please help?

( **Apps Script Docs:** https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/color-scheme )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommended Solution:**

You can use the [setSolidFill()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/fill#setSolidFill(Color)) method. You may refer to this sample script below to change a slide page background color:

**Script:**

```
function myFunction() { 
  var hex_color = '#2a2a2a'; //The background color set in dark gray
  var selection = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection();
  var currentPage = selection.getCurrentPage();
  var bg = currentPage.getBackground();
  bg.setSolidFill(hex_color);
}
```

**Result:**

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]